# How can I add a margin to an image in a div?

Tags: html, css

I've been trying to complete an HTML/CSS challenge from frontendmentor.io which wants me to create a layout for a QR code to be displayed.

[Webpage Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7HWmL.png)

The above link shows an image of what my webpage looks like currently. I've added a margin to the image that's inside the white-colored div, but it seems to overflow the div on the bottom and right sides. Ideally, the image should resize with the margin to fit in my specified div width of 375px, but it's not doing that. How can I fix this?

The code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"> <!-- displays site properly based on user's device -->

  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="./images/favicon-32x32.png">

  <title>Frontend Mentor | QR code component</title>

  <!-- Feel free to remove these styles or customise in your own stylesheet  -->
  <style>
    body { background-color: hsl(212, 45%, 89%); }
    .attribution { font-size: 11px; text-align: center; }
    .attribution a { color: hsl(228, 45%, 44%); }
    .tile { background-color: hsl(0, 0%, 100%); margin: auto; text-align: center; width: 375px; }
    .tile img { margin: 10px; }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="tile">
    <img src="./images/image-qr-code.png" alt="QR code">
    <br>
    Improve your front-end skills by building projects
    <br>
    Scan the QR code to visit Frontend Mentor and take your coding skills to the next level
  </div>

  <div class="attribution">
    Challenge by <a href="https://www.frontendmentor.io?ref=challenge" target="_blank">Frontend Mentor</a>.
    Coded by <a href="#">Joshua</a>.
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
.tile img {
  width:calc(100% - 20px)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Set `.tile img` to the following to resize the image to 100% of the size of the container `.tile`.

```
.tile img { margin: 10px; width:100%; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below things in between in style tag

```
body{
  min-height: 100vh;
}
.tile{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 80px; // use padding if you want
}
.tile img{max-width:70%; width:100%; height:auto}
```